# OSGi- Framework will only register certain Services

Tags: java, osgi

My project is composed of the following bundles, which define the Declarative Services with the given .xml files:

**characterbuilder.gui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="characterbuilder.gui">
   <implementation class="characterbuilder.gui.ApplicationFrame"/>
   <reference bind="setMenuScripting" cardinality="1..1" interface="characterbuilder.scripting.menu.IMenuScripting" name="IMenuScripting" policy="dynamic"/>
</scr:component>
```

**characterbuilder.pluginmanager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="characterbuilder.pluginmanager">
   <implementation class="characterbuilder.pluginmanager.implementation.PluginManager"/>
</scr:component>
```

**characterbuilder.scripting**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="characterbuilder.scripting">
   <implementation class="characterbuilder.scripting.internal.CharacterBuilderScripting"/>
   <reference bind="setGameSystem" cardinality="1..1" interface="characterbuilder.systemmanager.IGameSystem" name="IGameSystem" policy="static"/>
   <reference bind="setXMLHandler" cardinality="1..1" interface="characterbuilder.xmlhandling.xmlhandler.IXMLHandler" name="IXMLHandler" policy="static"/>
   <reference bind="setPluginManager" cardinality="1..1" interface="systemplugin.manager.IPluginManager" name="IPluginManager" policy="static"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="characterbuilder.scripting.menu.IMenuScripting"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

**characterbuilder.xmlhandling**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="character.builder.xml.handling">
   <implementation class="characterbuilder.xmlhandling.implementation.XMLHandler"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="characterbuilder.xmlhandling.xmlhandler.IXMLHandler"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

**characterbuilder.dummysystem**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="DummySystem">
   <implementation class="dummygamedefinition.systemmanager.DummySystemManager"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="characterbuilder.systemmanager.IGameSystem"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

When I use the "services" command from the console to get all the registered services, only IXMLHandler and IGameSystem are ever registered.

I've spent over a dozen hours over the last three days trying to get these services to work properly and I'm worst off than when I started, because I still haven't the slightest clue what to do and when I started I didn't feel so frustrated and stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are the bundles that register these services started? I banged my head on the same problem only to find that in the default run configuration Eclipse/Equinox does not start automatically all bundles.

Comment: I changed them all to autostart and all of them are now registering. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You wasted a lot of hours (as too many OSGi users do) by not having [Apache Felix Webconsole](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-web-console.html) with [aQute Xray](http://jpm4j.org/#!/p/sha/1E4A5D92C46D7EC829C537471068ED7FBF7B9433//0.0.0). Xray is a tab in webconsole when installed and it shows you with colors the state of the DS components, bundles, and services. There is also a warning on sign on bundles when they generated log message. Xray is heavily tooltipped, just hover over a bundle, log warning, service, or component to get more info. You can also click on these objects. These tools also works on Equinox since it is 100% OSGi.

P.S. I hope you are not really still using the XML files instead of the annotations?

Comment: I use the Component Definition Editor to manage the XML, if you're asking if I edit the XML manually. re: aQuite Xray, I'm on Windows 7 and according to the site there's no Windows support.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Where did you read that Xray doesn't support Windows? That's nonsense... of course it works on Windows.

Comment: @NeilBartlett It turns out I was looking in the wrong place. I clicked on install and that lead me to the installers for jpm, and I mistakenly though that was for xRay.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Cool. I strongly urge you to try Xray. You may have solved your problem this time, but next time you will not necessarily be so lucky. Xray gives you visibility into the state of all your component, which is the only chance of finding problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it the **characterbuilder.pluginmanager** does not provide any services but **characterbuilder.scripting reference** has a 1..1 static reference to **IPluginManager** which seems to be non existant from your example.

A good way (next to the web console and xray) to debug the application is the OSGi console.
Look for the unsatisfied services and the reason why they are unatisfied.

Best regards,
Mike